# Two disjoint sets of finite measure that are closed under summation and multiplication

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am looking for two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, which we denote by  $A,B$ with positive and finite measure (Lebesgue measure) that intersect only at ${\mathbb{Q}}$. Moreover, I want that both $A$ and $B$ will be closed under summation, taking negative, multiplication and taking inverse.

If anyone saw such sets, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Right, of course, it was corrected.

Comment: Now, by closure under sum, their intersection must contain $\Bbb Z$, and thus all the reciprocals of integers, and thus $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks again G.

Answer (score 2):

By [Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem) both $A$ and $B$ would contain open neighbourhood of the origin.